# Why My else part of the statement is not working?

Tags: php, html, if-statement, foreach

I have a script that append to the div whenever the function get call. I initialize $attrProductLoop to start at 1. But when $attrProductLoop is not 1 (2 and above) i don,t want to include add_more_attr button instead remove_attr button. there is an if statement in my PHP file in which to include a button base on the index (loop iteration) from the foreach loop. But I can figure out what is the problem.

I try to echo the list variable immediately after the foreach and it works,  inside if statement works but when I try to echo the variable inside the else part nothing shows up (the value of the id which is one in my case).

Here is the code:

```
<?php
     $sqlProductAttr = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM product_attributes WHERE product_id='$id'");
        $jj=0;
        while($rowProductAttr=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlProductAttr)) {
            $attrProduct[$jj]['product_id']=$rowProductAttr['product_id'];
            $attrProduct[$jj]['size_id']=$rowProductAttr['size_id'];
            $attrProduct[$jj]['color_id']=$rowProductAttr['color_id'];
            $attrProduct[$jj]['price']=$rowProductAttr['price'];
            $attrProduct[$jj]['qty']=$rowProductAttr['qty'];
            $attrProduct[$jj]['id']=$rowProductAttr['id'];
            $jj++;
        }
?>

   <div id="product_attr_box">
           <?php 
           $attrProductLoop=1;
           foreach($attrProduct AS $list) { ?>
           <div class="attr-row" id="attr_<?php echo $attrProductLoop ?>">
                    <div class="attr-item">
                    <label>Price &#8358;</label><br>
                    <input name="price[]" type="text" id="price" placeholder="Enter Product Price" value="<?php echo $list['price'] ?>"/>
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="attr-item">
                    <label>Quantity</label><br>
                    <input name="qty[]" type="text" id="qty" placeholder="Enter Product Quantity" value="<?php echo $list['qty'] ?>"/>
                    </div>
                  
                    <div class="attr-item">
                    <label></label><br>
                    <?php 
                    if($attrProductLoop==1){
                        ?>
                        <button type="button" onclick="add_more_attr()">Add More</button>
                        <?php
                    }else{
                      ?>
                      <button type="button" style="background: red" onclick="remove_attr('<?php echo $attrProductLoop;?>','<?php echo $list['id'];?>')">Remove</button>
                      <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                    </div>
   
           </div>
           <?php 
           $attrProductLoop++;
           } 
            ?>
           </div>

<script>
  var attr_count=1;
  function add_more_attr() {
    attr_count++;

    var size_html=jQuery('#attr_1 #size_id').html();
    var color_html=jQuery('#attr_1 #color_id').html();

    var html='<div class="attr-row" id="attr_'+attr_count+'"> <div class="attr-item"> <label>Price ₦</label><br> <input name="price[]" type="text" id="price" placeholder="Enter Product Price"> </div> <div class="attr-item"> <label>Quantity</label><br> <input name="qty[]" type="text" id="qty" placeholder="Enter Product Quantity"> </div> <div class="attr-item"> <label>Size</label><br> <select name="size_id[]" id="size_id" class="inv-text-inp">'+size_html+'</select> </div> <div class="attr-item"> <label>Color</label><br> <select name="color_id[]" id="color_id" class="inv-text-inp">'+color_html+'</select> </div> <div class="attr-item"> <label></label><br> <button type="button" style="background: red" onclick=remove_attr("'+attr_count+'")>X</button> </div> </div>';
    jQuery('#product_attr_box').append(html);
  }
  
  function remove_attr(attr_count,id) {
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: 'remove_product_attr.php',
      data: 'id='+id,
      type: 'post',
      success: function(result){
        jQuery('#attr_'+attr_count).remove();
      }
    });
      
  }
  
</script>
```

Comment: I'm seeing three `if` statements, which one isn't working as you expected? Please remove any other code that isn't germane to the problem

Comment: Ok i will remove

Comment: Ok here is the only one if statement. I have edited it.

Comment: Thanks. Also, just to be clear, you have run this code with the edits and it has the same problems as you originally identified?

Comment: Sounds like `$list['id']` might simply be empty. Have you _verified_ that by making a var_dump of $list at the beginning of your loop (or inside the else branch, if you don’t want to check on all records)?

Comment: Yeah. I var_dump of $list at the beginning of my loop, i got the array objects. But when i var_dump inside the else branch it output nothing.

Comment: I edited it again. I included the script.